# Generate and download report from SQL Server using SSRS with multiple parameters

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have designed a template in Report Builder and my report has 6 parameters:

```
Start Date, End Date, Source, Destination, Transaction, and Consignor
```

and my SQL table has the following columns:

```
[DATE], [SOURCE], [DESTINATION], [REFERENCE#], [ITEMCODE], [DESCRIPTION],
[UM], [PRICE], [QTY], [AMOUNT], [MFGDATE], [EXPDATE], [LOT#], [TRANS], [CONSIGNOR], [DRDATE]
```

I'm having a hard time writing the expressions for the parameters and could use some help please.

Comment: Do you need a stored procedure or a query to return the data?

Comment: @Programnik the reports will be generated on a regular basis, weekly and monthly,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query for this is fairly straight forward as it is all from a single table.

You would write a query like the following (assuming there are no Multi Value Parameters)

Your main dataset will be like this:

```
    Select 
    [DATE], [SOURCE], [DESTINATION], [REFERENCE#], [ITEMCODE], [DESCRIPTION],
    [UM], [PRICE], [QTY], [AMOUNT], [MFGDATE], [EXPDATE], [LOT#], [TRANS], [CONSIGNOR], [DRDATE]

    from your_table

where 
    your_table.Date between  @start_date and @end_date
    and your_table.Source =  @source
    and your_table.Destination=  @destination
    and your_table.Transaction=  @transaction
    and your_table.consignor=  @consignor
```

This will create all your parameters in the report

Now make sure for each parameter, you set the appropriate type.

I.E. start_date and end_date should be of type datetime etc.,

You can have multiple datasets in the report that derive the parameter value for each parameter.

for example.. you can have a source dataset like this

```
select distinct 
source
from your_table
where your_table.Date between  @start_date and @end_date
```

Now set the source parameter dataset to point to this for value.

This will only return the status that are available between the selected dates..

your destination dataset for the @destination parameter will be

```
select distinct Destination
from your_table
    where your_table.Date between  @start_date and @end_date
    and your_table.status = @status
```

Now you have to do the same for the rest of the parameters

Now depending on how you want to group and display.. you put a tablix and select your groupings / details etc from your main dataset. I don't think this is the place to explain how to do that.